# Importing CSV to MySQL with Load Data Infile

Tags: sql, mysql, csv, import, load-data-infile

I'm trying to load a CSV file into MySQL, and I keep getting syntax errors:

```
load data infile 'c:/worldminwage.csv' fields terminated by ',' enclosed
by '"' lines terminated by '\n' (YearlyWage, PercentGDP, Date
effective);
```

Can anyone help me get this working? Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Valid syntax is `LOAD DATA INFILE 'c:/worldminwage.csv' INTO TABLE tablename`.

You forgot to mention which table the data should go in. See [LOAD DATA INFILE Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html)

Answer (score 1):

I think This would be more batter

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'c:/worldminwage.csv' fields terminated by ',';
```

Because you will get rid of error like columns numbers are not matching in the .csv file and mysql table